# Outlook 2007 Exchange Server (Active Directory) on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-outlook-2007, active-directory

Is there a way or application that will allow Linux (Ubuntu) to integrate and exchange information (emails, calendar, etc.) with Outlook 2007 Exchange Server and Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this quick tuto will help you to import what you need. It's kinda tricky but works.

This HowTo might Help:
http://www.howtoforge.com/importing_outlook_express_into_thunderbird_evolution

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a link but the ubuntu forums are pretty good at keeping threads alive.  The instructions this guy has posted are fairly in depth but they should allow you to connect using thunderbird, ubuntu and exchange.

[LINK](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1237875)